# Laravel broadcasting every keystroke

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-broadcast

-Hey, I'm actually creating an online exam application I want to add a system that grants to teachers to see live what students are typing in a text area (or input) using **broadcast or laravelecho**.

-So my **Scenario** is when a student is typing, the teacher can see what he is typing if he presses on the button that concern the student.

I implemented all the app all i need is the way i can broadcast every keystroke.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? There is a whole part of the documentation dedicated to broadcasting, you will need to send on key input a request to the server, your server broadcasts the message and your teacher will see the input changes.

Comment: @Aless55 i've cheked the documentation, i just need a code example because i can't find how i can send a request after key input i'm pretty new to laravel.

Comment: are you using Vue.js or just Jquery in your frontend?

Comment: @Aless55 i'm using Jquery

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#input_id").keyup(function(){

    var value = $('#input_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"<your_url>",
        data :{
                'value' : value               
            },          
        success:function(res){
            $('#showSearchResult').html(res);
            }
       });

  });
});`
Something in this direction will work for the frontend

Comment: As an addition to @Aless55 I would recommend wrapping the actual $.ajax() call in some form of debounce method to prevent you from flooding your websocket server / provider. Underscore.js has an available one and depending on your project it might already be an included dependency. https://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: Another item to be mindful of is your desire to "broadcast every keystroke." It is very possible for events coming back from Laravel and your websocket to come out of order. Sending in a timestamp with the AJAX requests would help to resolve any out of order responses. Also for the same reason I would recommend sticking with sending the whole input value as @Aless55 showed above so that the full message is always included on what's shown to the teacher vs your initial desire to broadcast every keystroke which could turn into a headache especially if the AJAX calls start to fail.

Comment: @GilesWells you are totally right, He might also incorporate some mechanism that only broadcasts input changes of watched students.